# How to synchonized this lambda statement?

Tags: java

Java / JDK 19. How to synchonized this lambda statement?

```java
package sybex.ch00.exercies;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Q03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel().forEach(s -> data.add(s));
        System.out.println(data.size());
    }
}
```

I read book, they said after `synchronized` lamba will make thread safe, and return `100`, but I don't know how to do. Please guide me.

Comment: Can you show what exactly the book said? I think people can misunderstand your question

Comment: Note that using `parallel()` in this case is extremely inefficient. Removing `parallel()` will make the code and correct, and faster (especially compare to fixing this by adding synchronization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No special trick to it, just use a `synchronized` block:

```
public class Q03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel().forEach(s -> {
            synchronized(data) { data.add(s); }
        });
        System.out.println(data.size());
    }
}
```

Depending on the context you are running this in you will have to choose what object to synchronize on. Here `data` is a good choice, or you could create an object to lock on:

```
public class Q03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();
        Object lock = new Object();
        IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel().forEach(s -> {
            synchronized(lock) { data.add(s); }
        });
        System.out.println(data.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From a `Stream` point of view, external synchronization is the **wrong** way to do it (forced by a bad use of side effects). The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) state this about side effects:

> Side-effects in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in general, discouraged, as they can often lead to unwitting violations of the statelessness requirement, as well as other thread-safety hazards.

Also:

> Many computations where one might be tempted to use side effects can be more safely and efficiently expressed without side-effects, such as using reduction instead of mutable accumulators. However, side-effects such as using println() for debugging purposes are usually harmless. A small number of stream operations, such as forEach() and peek(), can operate only via side-effects; these should be used with care.

Additionally external synchronization will hurt performance:

> If executed in parallel, the non-thread-safety of ArrayList would cause incorrect results, and adding needed synchronization would cause contention, undermining the benefit of parallelism. Furthermore, using side-effects here is completely unnecessary; the forEach() can simply be replaced with a reduction operation that is safer, more efficient, and more amenable to parallelization

The correct way to do it (for `Stream`s), would be to use a [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html).

```
List<Integer> data = IntStream.range(0, 100)
        .parallel()
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(data.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`Collections.synchronizedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> data = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel().forEach(s -> data.add(s));
    System.out.println(data.size());
}
```

Just take care when you use the iterator of that list, see the linked JavaDocs.

Alternatively you can use one of the concurrent collections in `java.util.concurrent`, but the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` there could have significant performance issues for the case you showed. On the other hand I didn't check performance for the solution above.